# Update SID in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sid

My user was deleted from the Active Directory and recreated. When running the `select suser_sid`, I notice that it shows the old SID.

Is there a way to update it to my new SID? 
I am DBA Admin on SQL Server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't `ALTER` the SID of a `LOGIN`, no (notice there is no `SID` option in [ALTER LOGIN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)). You'll need to recreate the `LOGIN` by dropping the old one and recreating it and giving it the old permissions.

This will orphan any associated `USER`s, so you will then need to remap them to the new `LOGIN` using `ALTER USER` in the databases it has a login in:

```
ALTER USER [Domain\User] WITH LOGIN = [Domain\User];
```

Comment: My access was via an AD group to SQL Server. I had an old login with my user that I wasn't really using, so I deleted it. I also played around with [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/767094/change-sql-server-user-sid) registry setting as well. After deleting my login, I rerun the select suser_sid and got my new SID.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you cannot update SID for a login. From the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

> NAME = login_name The new name of the login that is being renamed. If
> this is a Windows login, the SID of the Windows principal
> corresponding to the new name **must match** the SID associated with the
> login in SQL Server. The new name of a SQL Server login cannot contain
> a backslash character ().