# The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Table_Name', database 'DatabaseName', schema 'dbo'

Tags: sql-server

I am using ***Integrated Security*** in a SQL Server connection string, but it shows the error:

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Table_Name', database 'DatabaseName', schema 'dbo'.

I have no choice but using ***Integrated Security***. I have find some similar questions, but they can not solve my problem.

Comment: The user does not have `SELECT` permission on that table. use `GRANT SELECT ON Table_Name TO xxx`

Comment: Integrated Security has very little to do with it. You need to grant your account access to the table.

Comment: Who is the account of Integrated Security?

Comment: If I don't use **Integrated Security**, there will be no error. @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: That’s because you are using a completely different login . And that login has been granted access.

Comment: The integrated security account is your windows account.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - it can also be a windows group his account belongs to.

Comment: Correct. Didn't want to confuse the OP further.

Comment: My problem is solved, thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update SID in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212482/update-sid-in-sql-server)

Comment: I tried another method, but I think the answer you gave me may help, thank you.@Charlieface

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that the computer name has been changed, and the database cannot detect this change. Delete the original user of the database and create a new user to solve it. This does help to me.